# How to use post request response value to create a put request in swagger/open api definition

Tags: openapi

I have created servers -url and path for a post request .I want to use the value of one of the key from post response(this returns a url ). The url value needs to be used to create a put request. How to define this in open api specification 3.
I tried using parameters in the path section ,but the parameters are appended to servers -url created.

Comment: Can you add examples of a POST response and a subsequent PUT request?

Comment: Hi @Helen , here is the example post response : { "id": "Qa001", "PutUrl": "qa-files.s3.amazonaws.com/image/…", "message": "Use the pre_signed_put_url to upload your file into S3." } . I need to use the url value in the Puturl key and create a raise a put request . The servers -url which I am using for post is different and I need to raise a put request for the above puturl key which does not need a server -url –